# open textbox on calender day click

Tags: c#, .net, calendar

I have seen number of posts for this solution , But not getting satisfying answer
I am trying to Simply add textbox +button on Calender cell and open it on cell click ,

I can make a popup open on cells click .But not with `Textbox` of `CellSize`,

```
   <asp:Calendar
            ID="Calendar2" 
            runat="server"
            NextPrevFormat="FullMonth"
            SelectionMode="Day"
            DayNameFormat="Full"
            OnDayRender="Calendar1_DayRender"
            VisibleDate="10/7/2008" OnSelectionChanged="Calendar2_SelectionChanged"
            >

        </asp:Calendar>
```

and calling DayRender event

```
protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
{
     Label lbl = new Label();

     lbl.Text = e.Day.DayNumberText.ToString();
     lbl.Attributes.Add("onclick", "JavaScript:void(window.open('Test/Default.aspx'))");
     lbl.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");

     e.Cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
}
```

How can I do it for a `Textbox`?

Comment: Are you referring to the cell inside a grid view? If so, then does your gridview cell contains both textbox and button?

Comment: No .. it is just simple calender control .. I have updated the code

Comment: Are you trying to show up textbox on button click for each cell?

Answer (score 0):

Inside you calendar event 
    protected void Calendar1_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
        {
            Button btn = new Button();

```
        btn.Text = "+";
        btn.Attributes.Add("onclick", "javascript:return btnClick(" + e.Day.DayNumberText + ")");
        btn.Style.Add("cursor", "pointer");

        TextBox txt = new TextBox();
        txt.ID = e.Day.DayNumberText.ToString();
        txt.Attributes.Add("style", "display:none;");
        txt.Attributes.Add("onclick", "JavaScript:void(window.open('Test/Default.aspx'))");
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(txt);
        e.Cell.Controls.Add(btn);
    }
```

Add the script tag in the aspx file

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function btnClick(id){
        var txt = document.getElementById(id);
        txt.attributes.removeNamedItem("style");
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Since you've used javascript, i adhered to your compatibility. But i suggest you to used jquery.